# How to Find the Longest Palindrome (java)

Tags: java, string, joptionpane, palindrome

Hi I've been doing this java program, i should input a string and output the longest palindrome that can be found .. 
but my program only output the first letter of the longest palindrome .. i badly need your help .. thanks!

SHOULD BE:

INPUT : abcdcbbcdeedcba
OUTPUT : bcdeedcb
There are two palindrome strings : bcdcb and bcdeedcb

BUT WHEN I INPUT : abcdcbbcdeedcba
output : b

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Palindrome5
{   public static void main(String args[])
    {   String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input String : ", "INPUT", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        String subword = "";
        String revword = "";
        String Out = "";
        int size = word.length();
        boolean c;

        for(int x=0; x<size; x++)
        {   for(int y=x+1; y<size-x; y++)
            {   subword = word.substring(x,y);
                c = comparisonOfreverseword(subword);
                if(c==true)
                {
                    Out = GetLongest(subword);
                }
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Longest Palindrome : " + Out, "OUTPUT", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

    public static boolean comparisonOfreverseword(String a)
        {   String rev = "";
            int tempo = a.length();
            boolean z=false;
            for(int i = tempo-1; i>=0; i--)
            {
                char let = a.charAt(i);
                rev = rev + let;
            }
            if(a.equalsIgnoreCase(rev))
            {
                z=true;
            }
            return(z);
        }
    public static String GetLongest(String sWord)
        {
            int sLength = sWord.length();
            String Lpalindrome = "";
            int storage = 0;
            if(storage<sLength)
            { 
                storage = sLength;

                Lpalindrome = sWord;
            }
            return(Lpalindrome);
        }
}
```

Comment: method1 and method2 are not the most descriptive names...

Comment: What has swing code to do with this question? Nothing! Please remove all code not directly relevant to the question, as per [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Also, you would do well to follow [standard java coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), especially for names.

Comment: Lighten up, Bohemian. I mean, two lines of Swing? And where is it written that example code must comply to standard coding conventions? I agree on both issues that it would be better but no need to be anal about it IMO.

Comment: im really sorry, i'm just new with this language.. and my professor only taught us to use JOption with the swing .. thanks though! :)

Answer (score 1):

modified program..this program will give the correct output

```
package pract1;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Palindrome5
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {



    String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input String : ", "INPUT", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    String subword = "";
    String revword = "";
    String Out = "";

    int size = word.length();
    boolean c;
        String Lpalindrome = "";
        int  storage=0;

  String out="";

    for(int x=0; x<size; x++)
    {   for(int y=x+1; y<=size; y++)
        {   subword = word.substring(x,y);
            c = comparisonOfreverseword(subword);
            if(c==true)
            {
                 int sLength = subword.length();


                   if(storage<sLength)
                 { 
                     storage = sLength;

                     Lpalindrome = subword;
                     out=Lpalindrome;


                 }

            }
        }
    }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Longest Palindrome : " + out, "OUTPUT", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}

public static boolean comparisonOfreverseword(String a)
    {   String rev = "";
        int tempo = a.length();
        boolean z=false;
        for(int i = tempo-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            char let = a.charAt(i);
            rev = rev + let;
        }
        if(a.equalsIgnoreCase(rev))
        {
            z=true;
        }
        return(z);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two bugs:

1.

```
for(int y=x+1; y<size-x; y++)
```

should be

```
for(int y=x+1; y<size; y++)
```

since you still want to go all the way to the end of the string. With the previous loop, since x increases throughout the loop, your substring sizes decrease throughout the loop (by removing x characters from their end).

2.

You aren't storing the longest string you've found so far or its length. The code

```
int storage = 0;
if(storage<sLength) { 
    storage = sLength;
    ...
```

is saying 'if the new string is longer than zero characters, then I will assume it is the longest string found so far and return it as LPalindrome'. That's no help, since we may have previously found a longer palindrome.

If it were me, I would make a static variable (e.g. longestSoFar) to hold the longest palindrome found so far (initially empty). With each new palindrome, check if the new one is longer than longestSoFar. If it is longer, assign it to longestSoFar. Then at the end, display longestSoFar.

In general, if you're having trouble 'remembering' something in the program (e.g. previously seen values) you have to consider storing something statically, since local variables are forgotten once their methods finish.

Comment: I would suggest leaving the 'static realm' altogether. Make the methods and new fields non-static and create an instance in the main method on which you call a 'start' method. It may not be necessary now but I think it is good practice to program in objects rather than classes. Also, if this program is ever expanded, incorporated in other code or even just unit tested for that matter, the static fields will immediately lead to problems.

Comment: Well ok then, but that is a complete code rewrite compared to a two line fix that makes the program work as specified in the question. In what way would the static fields immediately lead to problems?

Comment: If the class is incorporated in other code and two instances of it are created, their state will interace unexpectedly. If it is expanded by another developer, he/she will (and should) not expect statics to be used for maintaining algorithmic state and need more time to find out how to use this class. If the class is used as an imported library then it might not even be possible to change the code to their needs. If a unit test is written for this class then subsequent tests could see the remaining static state of previous tests and therefore not be independent of each other.

Comment: In general: using statics for state is usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

public class LongestPalindrome {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
String S= "abcdcba";
printLongestPalindrome(S);
}


public static void printLongestPalindrome(String S)
{
    int maxBack=-1;
    int maxFront = -1;
    int maxLength=0;
    for (int potentialCenter = 0 ; potentialCenter < S.length();potentialCenter ++ )
    {   
        int back = potentialCenter-1;
        int front = potentialCenter + 1;
        int longestPalindrome = 0;
        while(back >=0 && front<S.length() && S.charAt(back)==S.charAt(front))
        {
            back--;
            front++;
            longestPalindrome++;

        }
        if (longestPalindrome > maxLength)
        {
            maxLength = longestPalindrome+1;
            maxBack = back + 1;
            maxFront = front;
        }
        back = potentialCenter;
        front = potentialCenter + 1;
        longestPalindrome=0;
        while(back >=0 && front<S.length() && S.charAt(back)==S.charAt(front))
        {
            back--;
            front++;
            longestPalindrome++;
        }
        if (longestPalindrome > maxLength)
        {
            maxLength = longestPalindrome;
            maxBack = back + 1;
            maxFront = front;
        }

    }


    if (maxLength == 0) System.out.println("There is no Palindrome in the given String");
    else{
        System.out.println("The Longest Palindrome is " + S.substring(maxBack,maxFront) + "of " + maxLength);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have my own way to get longest palindrome in a random word. check this out

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println(longestPalSubstr(in.nextLine().toLowerCase()));


}




static String longestPalSubstr(String str) {

       char [] input = str.toCharArray();
       Set<CharSequence> out = new HashSet<CharSequence>();

      int n1 = str.length()-1;


      for(int a=0;a<=n1;a++)
       {
          for(int m=n1;m>a;m--)
          {

          if(input[a]==input[m])
          {

           String nw = "",nw2="";

           for (int y=a;y<=m;y++)
           {

                nw=nw+input[y];
           }
           for (int t=m;t>=a;t--)
           {

               nw2=nw2+input[t];
           }


           if(nw2.equals(nw))
           {

                out.add(nw);


               break;
           }
       }

     }

   }


    int a = out.size();
    int maxpos=0;
    int max=0;
    Object [] s = out.toArray();

    for(int q=0;q<a;q++)
    {

        if(max<s[q].toString().length())
        {
            max=s[q].toString().length();
            maxpos=q;
        }
    }


   String output = "longest palindrome is : "+s[maxpos].toString()+" and the lengths is : "+ max; 
   return output;



}
```

this method will return the max length palindrome and the length of it. its a way that i tried and got the answer. and this method will run whether its a odd length or even length.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LongestPalindrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Integer> result = findLongestPalindrome("ayrgabcdeedcbaghihg123444456776");
        result.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("String:" + k + " Value:" + v));
    }


    private static HashMap<String, Integer> findLongestPalindrome(String str) {
        int i = 0;
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        while (i < str.length()) {
            String alpha = String.valueOf(str.charAt(i));
            if (str.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) != str.lastIndexOf(str.charAt(i))) {
                String pali = str.substring(i, str.lastIndexOf(str.charAt(i)) + 1);
                if (isPalindrome(pali)) {
                    map.put(pali, pali.length());
                    i = str.lastIndexOf(str.charAt(i));
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String input) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= input.length() / 2; i++) {
            if (input.charAt(i) != input.charAt(input.length() - 1 - i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }

}
```

This approach is simple.

Output:
String:abcdeedcba Value:10
String:4444 Value:4
String:6776 Value:4
String:ghihg Value:5

Answer (score -1):

This is my own way to get longest palindrome. this will return the length and the palindrome word

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println(longestPalSubstr(in.nextLine().toLowerCase()));


}




static String longestPalSubstr(String str) {

       char [] input = str.toCharArray();
       Set<CharSequence> out = new HashSet<CharSequence>();

      int n1 = str.length()-1;


      for(int a=0;a<=n1;a++)
       {
          for(int m=n1;m>a;m--)
          {

          if(input[a]==input[m])
          {

           String nw = "",nw2="";

           for (int y=a;y<=m;y++)
           {

                nw=nw+input[y];
           }
           for (int t=m;t>=a;t--)
           {

               nw2=nw2+input[t];
           }


           if(nw2.equals(nw))
           {

                out.add(nw);


               break;
           }
       }

     }

   }


    int a = out.size();
    int maxpos=0;
    int max=0;
    Object [] s = out.toArray();

    for(int q=0;q<a;q++)
    {

        if(max<s[q].toString().length())
        {
            max=s[q].toString().length();
            maxpos=q;
        }
    }


   String output = "longest palindrome is : "+s[maxpos].toString()+" and the lengths is : "+ max; 
   return output;



}
```

this method will return the max length palindrome and the length of it. its a way that i tried and got the answer. and this method will run whether its a odd length or even length.